# How to remove those specified label component by fastest method

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

### Cross post [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/184172/how-to-remove-those-specified-label-component-by-fastest-method/)

Suppose I have an such binary image

```
Mat img(1000, 2000, CV_8UC1);
randu(img, Scalar(0), Scalar(255));
inRange(img, Scalar(160), Scalar(200), img);
```

I will use `connectedComponentsWithStats` to label the binary `img`

```
Mat labels, stats, centroids;
int counts_img = connectedComponentsWithStats(img, labels, stats, centroids);
```

And I will specify some labels to remove from `labels`.

```
vector<int> drop_label(counts_img - 3);
iota(drop_label.begin(), drop_label.end(), 1);
```

Of course I can do it with following method:

```
Mat img(1000, 2000, CV_8UC1);
randu(img, Scalar(0), Scalar(255));
inRange(img, Scalar(160), Scalar(200), img);

Mat labels, stats, centroids;
int counts_img = connectedComponentsWithStats(img, labels, stats, centroids);

vector<int> drop_label(counts_img - 3);
iota(drop_label.begin(), drop_label.end(), 1);

//start to count the time.
double start_time = (double)getTickCount();

Mat select = img.clone() = 0;
int img_height = img.rows, img_width = img.cols;
for (int i = 0; i < img_height; i++) {
    int*plabels = labels.ptr<int>(i);
    uchar*pselect = select.ptr<uchar>(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < img_width; j++) {
        if (find(drop_label.begin(), drop_label.end(), plabels[j]) != drop_label.end())
            pselect[j] = 255;
    }
}

Mat result = img - select;

//total time
double total_time = ((double)getTickCount() - start_time) / getTickFrequency();
cout << "total time: " << total_time << "s" << endl;
```

> `total time: 96.8676s`

As you see, I can do it indeed,  and as I know, the `.ptr` is the fastest methd. but I have  to say I cannot bear the function `find` cost my so many time. Any body can tell me a fastest method to do this?

Comment: I just skimmed over your question so I might say something stupid but, if you want to avoid the linear cost of std::find, why not sorting your vector first then do dichotomic searches (with e.g. [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)) ?

Comment: Actually, since drop_label = {1, 2, ..., n} why not just check whether x is between 1 and n (included) rather than creating that table and using find ? (to be honest, I don't really know opencv so I'm not sure what you want to do, I'm just noticing random things irrelevant to opencv...)

Comment: @Caninonos Sorry, I cannot realize `lower_bound` can to this still

Comment: @Caninonos NoNoNo. `drop_label` can have any label, I just make a example for specify what I want to do.

Comment: maybe [replace_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) instead of the for is better... (cv::Mat has begin and end)

Comment: @api55 `replace_if` can operate a `Mat`?

Comment: What you want to do here is create a lookup table: `iota` from 0 to max label in image, then set to 0 those elements corresponding to the labels you want to drop. Then for each pixel simply look up the value and replace with the one in the lookup table. I'm sure OpenCV has some function to apply a lookup table too.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Good advice. Thanks very much, I will give a try right now.

Comment: @CrisLuengo See answer in following. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @tem, yes you can use the `std` functions with `cv::Mat` you need to use [`cv::Mat::begin<T>()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a33ee3bc402827f587a5ad64b568d6986) and end.  (T is uchar in your case) And it will work :) also std::transform may work for your current answer, it may not be much faster, but maybe a little bit shorter. However the lookup table certainly is a better idea

Answer (score 1):

As the CrisLuengo's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48664698/how-to-remove-those-specified-label-component-by-fastest-method#comment84352311_48664698), I have increased the `99s` to `0.004s` now

```
Mat img(1000, 2000, CV_8UC1);
randu(img, Scalar(0), Scalar(255));
inRange(img, Scalar(160), Scalar(200), img);

Mat labels, stats, centroids;
int counts_img = connectedComponentsWithStats(img, labels, stats, centroids);

vector<int> drop_label(counts_img - 3);
iota(drop_label.begin(), drop_label.end(), 1);


vector<int> replace_table(counts_img);
iota(replace_table.begin(), replace_table.end(), 0);
for (int i : drop_label)
    replace_table[i] = 0;

//start to count the time.
double start_time = (double)getTickCount();

Mat select = img.clone() = 0;
int img_height = img.rows, img_width = img.cols;
for (int i = 0; i < img_height; i++) {
    int*plabels = labels.ptr<int>(i);
    uchar*pselect = select.ptr<uchar>(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < img_width; j++) {
        if (replace_table[plabels[j]] != 0)
            pselect[j] = 255;
    }
}

Mat result = img - select;

//total time
double total_time = ((double)getTickCount() - start_time) / getTickFrequency();
cout << "total time: " << total_time << "s" << endl;
```

Comment: Glad it's helpful!